# How do I get Django's ORM to check if model HAS or HAS ALL of a certain relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've read that it's bad to avoid large IN clauses, because they are slow (especially with PostgreSQL).

Say I have a class called Fridge, and a classes called Vegetables and Condiments.

Both of these have ManyToMany relationships between themselves and Fridge.

So something like:

```
class Fridge(models.Model):
     condiments = models.ManyToManyField(Condiments)
     vegetables = models.ManyToManyField(Vegetables)
```

And here we have a QuerySet that represents our white fridges:

```
qs = Fridges.objects.filter(color='white')
```

**First question**:

"Given a list of condiment IDs, get me all the fridges that have ANY of those condiments in them (modifying the original QuerySet).""

**Second query**:

"Given a list of vegetable IDs, get me all the fridges that have ALL of those vegetables in them (modifying the original QuerySet)."

How on earth would I do that without building a list of fridge IDs and adding an IN clause to my queryset?

Here are solutions that do it with IN clauses (name changed versions of my existing solutions):

First query:

```
    condiment_ids = [...] # list of condiment IDs
    condiments = Condiment.objects.filter(
        id__in=condiment_ids).all()
    condiment_fridges = None
    for condiment in condiments:
        qs = condiment.fridge_set.all()
        if not condiment_fridges:
            condiment_fridges = qs
        else:
            condiment_fridges = condiment_fridges | qs
    qs = qs.filter(id__in=[l.id for l in condiment_fridges])
```

Second query:

```
    vegetable_ids = [...] # list of vegetable IDs
    vegetables = vegetable.objects.filter(id__in=vegetable_ids).all()
    vegetable_fridges = None
    for vegetable in vegetables:
        qs = vegetable.location_set.all()
        if not vegetable_fridges:
            vegetable_fridges = qs
        else:
            vegetable_fridges = vegetable_fridges & qs
    qs = qs.filter(id__in=[l.id for l in vegetable_fridges])
```

These solutions seem horrible and hackish and I was wondering if there was a better way to do them with Django's ORM.

Comment: You have some list of ID's. You need to find some objects with ID's that are **in** this list. How can you possibly avoid in's here? I think you can't. More interesting question is where does this list of ID's come from?

Comment: The list of IDs comes from a form multi-select field, that said, I would be more likely to get the list of vegetables or whatnot from a cache in production, perhaps.

Comment: How many choices are there? I don't think there are more than ~ 100 vegetables or condiments each (I am not a cook :-)), and this don't look like large numbers. Caching will help anyway.

Comment: True, there are maybe 10 vegetables or 5 condiments, but there are several hundred fridges (this could become thousands).

Comment: Even thousands of fridges doesn't look like a high load here. Do some profiling and see if there is any problem. If the load becomes really high, I think fridges can be stored in sets and retrieved with unions / itersections. Redis has good [set support](http://redis.io/commands#set). But don't do premature optimization, it's evil, you know.

Comment: Ah, I was going by this article that claims that with PostgreSQL, using large IN statements is a poor idea: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2012/06/04/djangocon-postgres.html

Plus it just seems like ugly, hard-to-read code slicing QuerySets together and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question then all you need is:

```
Fridge.objects.filter(condiments__in=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

There might be a more efficient way to find if a Fridge has all the condiments. Not tested but something like:

```
max_conds = Condiment.objects.all().count()
result = Fridge.objects.annotate(conds=Count('condiments')).filter(conds=max_conds)
```

That could well be slower though depending on your db backend and the number of rows for each model.

Comment: First example looks like it could be excellent, I'll try it. Second isn't quite there - it's not whether something has all all condiments, but whether it has all the condiments in a given list, which is more complex I think. Could do it by chaining multiple of the first though, perhaps.

    `for id in condiment_ids: qs = qs.filter(condiments__in=[id]);